# PHP how to read comments from twig file?

Tags: php, twig, php-7

How can I read comments in **twig files** using PHP?

test.twig:

```
{# Holy cow Twig is awesome! #}
```

PHP:

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents("test.twig"));
$comments = array();
foreach($tokens as $token) {
    if($token[0] == T_COMMENT || $token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
        $comments[] = $token[1];
    }
}
print_r($comments);
```

Result:

```
Array ( )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `{#` and `#}` aren't supported tokens for this function. Either you need to use some other library (if exists) or write your own function. List of parser tokens: http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: You need to understand [how to twig deletes comments](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/f0a4fa678465491947554f6687c5fca5e482f8ec/lib/Twig/Lexer.php#L18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use regex?

```
$txt = file_get_contents("test.twig");
if ( preg_match_all ("/{#([^}]*)#}/", $txt, $matches) )
  print_r($matches[1]);
```